# Temporary features - Good practices

Tags: design

I work in a company where we do administrative tasks for other companies. With covid-19, there are many temporary laws to take into account.
My company did as it did before : simply creating the new field in the table and adapt the programs. I know it is bad practice because over time, we have table with 100+ columns, most of them being legacy. Many programs also have code that have been hastily writen, leading to the code becoming difficult to maintain.

Considering it requires new columns in the database tables, what would be the best practice to develop these features and then push them aside when we don't need them anymore ?

Concerning the database, I was considering creating child tables that inherit from the tables I need.
Concerning the programs, I would create a new git branch where I implement this feature. If I then need new features/patch from the master branch, I would merge it from a copy of the master branch.

Is that a good idea or are there any better practices that have proven themselves ?

Comment: (SQL) database tables cannot "inherit" from another table. Could you please clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: Having a table with 1:1 mapping for the temporary data is definitely a viable solution.  Regarding how to manage the larger capability that surrounds that information, many times that's something you have to address on a case by case basis.  Compliance requirements vary widely and can have extensive impact, or very minimal impact.  This is a place where microservices can be used to bolster the core functionality.

Comment: @PhilipKendall table inheritance is a somewhat common SQL extension, notably in Oracle. Postgres also has some support.

Comment: "_temporary_ laws" hmm i'd been keeping that code for the next one

Comment: @PhilipKendall I was thinking about this : https://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/tutorial-inheritance.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key issue you seem to be describing is a lack of modularity.  In other words, your system must be altered at a fundamental level since there are no mechanisms to add those features as a module.

There are different levels of **modularity**, and what is most appropriate depends on what kind of application you are building.  Each of these represent different types of modularity:

- **Plugins:** popularized in desktop applications, plug-ins extend the base product with new features.  It could be an editing mode, or a way to process pictures, etc.
- **Extensions:** extensions integrate more pervasively, but has the same impact.  The extension can add new tables, as well as code that works with those tables.  Extensions can be either server side or client side.
- **Microservices:** encapsulate a set of functionality on the server side.  A microservice is intended to be fully encapsulated and deployed as an independent unit.

These are not the only way of extending your application.  The key take away here is that you have to design for modularity.  When you have temporary features, you need to be able to add support for the feature for the time it's necessary, and then remove that capability when it is no longer necessary.

So, inside your module you have to decide how to store data:

- Don't extend existing tables.  Either add a new table with 1:1 mapping of records, or track that information outside of your database
- Plan how the user interface gets the new fields, etc.

The bottom line is that it takes longer to build modular code.  There's more to plan and think about.  However, if the infrastructure that makes modular code is in place, then it does make it easier to add your temporary features, and remove them when they are no longer necessary.